# Rendering data from an array of objects

Tags: reactjs

I have integrated the search filter and retrieved the json data( array of objects ) using the post method based on the search term. The json output is given below:

```
[
  {"taxi_code":"CT0001","class":"0"},
  {"taxi_code":"CT0002","class":"0"},
  {"taxi_code":"CT0003","class":"0"}
]
```

But the json data is not rendered to the DisplayTable component even using map method. What i did wrong?? Using `console.log(<DisplayTable data={queryResult} />`),  i got this type of output: `Object { props={...},  _store={...},  $$typeof=Symbol {}, more...}`

```
class Results extends Component
{
      constructor(props){
                 super(props);
                 this.state={searchTerm:''};       
      }
      render(){
          return(<div id="results" className="search-results">
                  {this.props.data}
                  <SearchInput className="search-input" onChange={e=>this.searchUpdated(e)} />
                 </div>);
      }
      searchUpdated (e) {
          this.setState={searchTerm: e};
          var queryResult;
          axios.post(config.api.url + 'public/getAttributesbyname', {'searchTerm':e,'name':this.props.data})
              .then(response => {

               var queryResult = response.data;
              render()
              {

              return (<DisplayTable data={queryResult}/>);
              }
              })
              .catch(response => {

              });
      }
  }

 class DisplayTable extends Component
 {
    render()
    {
        return this.props.data.map((alldata)=> {
            return <div className="station">{alldata.taxi_code}</div>;
        });
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please, read best practices. This type of coding is horrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several mistakes in your code,

1. You can't return values from asynchronous function(`axios.post`)
2. `this.setState` is method and you have to call it `this.setState()` but not assign value to it

I think in this case you don't need handle state from input field `searchTerm`, you can get value from input and use it., however you should handle state for data which you get from server.

I've refactored your example, and now it looks like this

```
class Results extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [] };
  }

  render(){
    return <div id="results" className="search-results">
      <DisplayTable data={ this.state.data } />
      <SearchInput 
        className="search-input" 
        onChange={ e => this.searchUpdated(e) } 
      />
    </div>;
  }

  searchUpdated (e) {
    axios
      .post(config.api.url + 'public/getAttributesbyname', {
        searchTerm: e.target.value, 
        name: this.props.data 
      })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ data: response.data });
      })
     .catch(response => {});
  }
}

class DisplayTable extends Component {
  render() {
    const stations = this.props.data.map((alldata, index) => {
      return <div className="station" key={ index }>{ alldata.taxi_code }</div>;
    });

    return <div>{ stations }</div>
  }
}
```